# distortion of lengths when constructing a Torus by a quotient space

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry, quotient-spaces

[Currently reading Geometry of Surfaces (Stillwell)]

One can create a Torus by joining opposite sites of a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. When joining the second pair, the lengths from  $\mathbb{R}^2$ get distorted because of the circular form of the torus.

The book now says, one can define the torus as a quotient space $\mathbb{R}^2 / \Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is the group of transformations , generated by the two transformations which moves the respectively opposite sites together. Thus, one can carry the local geometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$ over to $\mathbb{R}^2 / \Gamma$.

Sure, this does resolve the problem of length distortion, but why would someone conduct euclidean geometry with the "wrong" lengths ?

Comment: Do you mean embedding the torus as a donut in $\Bbb{R}^3$, the euclidean distance becomes a metric on the torus ? If so what embedding do you choose ? As smooth manifolds the donut and $\Bbb{R^2/Z^2}$ are the same, but not as Riemaniann manifolds, where the natural metric on the torus $\Bbb{R^2/Z^2}$. is the one coming from $\Bbb{R}^2$ because this metric is invariant under the natural group law of $\Bbb{R^2/Z^2}$.

Comment: What's "wrong" with those lengths? Why *wouldn't* a mathematician be interested and curious about some new construction of length?

Comment: the thing is, I do not know what embedding is chosen, nor what that even is, I am way at the beginning. But I guess, the way I see the torus (donut in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I am thinking of a flexible paper piece which I glue together to get a torus), it is regarded as Riemann mfd, but the way the book sees it, it is a smooth mfd. But admittedly, I am just using words I do not know the meaning of.